# AlloyUI Form Builder trying to access the elements created dynamically

Tags: javascript, xml, bounding-box, formbuilder, alloy-ui

I have built a dynamic form using AlloyUI form builder. I want to capture the elements which ever I drag and drop in the bounding box.
I came across something like this:

function saveFieldsForm(){
    var formXML = '';

```
myFormBuilder.get('fields').each(
function(item, index, collection) {
    var dataType = item.get('dataType'),
        indexType = item.get('indexType'),
        label = item.get('label'),
        multiple = item.get('multiple'),
        name = item.get('name'),
        options = item.get('options'),
        readOnly = item.get('readOnly'),
        repeatable = item.get('repeatable'),
        required = item.get('required'),
        showLabel = item.get('showLabel'),
        type = item.get('type'),
        tip = item.get('tip'),
        predefinedValue= item.get('predefinedValue'),
        width = item.get('width');

    var fieldXML = '<field>';
    fieldXML += '<type>' + type + '</type>';
    fieldXML += '<name>' + name + '</name>';
    fieldXML += '<required>' + required + '</required>';
    fieldXML += '<tip>' + tip + '</required>';
    fieldXML += '<predefinedValue>' + predefinedValue + '</predefinedValue>';        
    fieldXML += '</field>';
    alert("fieldXML: "+ fieldXML);
    formXML += fieldXML;
});

formXML += '</root>';
 alert("formXML: "+ formXML);

 AUI().use('aui-io-request',
            function(A) {           

        A.io.request(
            '<%=ajaxURL%>',{
                data: {                         

                    formXML : formXML,

                },
                dataType: 'json',
                on: {                                                                                            
                        success: function(data) {   
                            alert("Your form has been saved!")

                        },

                        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                            alert("Error, the content has not been saved! Please try again...");    
                            console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);                       

                            }           
                    }
            });    
            });
```

}

In the above code I understand that the drag and dropped field are being captured but i don't understand the item, index and collection fields inside the function in the very second line of code. What are these values and from where are these getting populated?
Please help!!!

Answer (score 2):

The `myFormBuilder.get('fields')` returns an [Alloy UI ArrayList](http://alloyui.com/versions/1.5.x/api/classes/ArrayList.html#method_each) which is where you get the `each` function. The parameters for the `callback` come from "within" the `ArrayList`.

I recently used the form-builder and captured my form in a very similar manner. However, I saved mine as `JSON`.

```
var formDefinition = [];

var parser = function(fields, container){
  fields.each(function(item, index) {
    var surveyElement = {};
    var properties = item.getProperties();

    properties.forEach(function(property) {
      var attr = property.attributeName;
      surveyElement[attr] =  item.get(attr); 
    })
    surveyElement.name = item.get('name');

    var children = item.getAttrs()['fields']
    if(children && children.size() > 0){
      surveyElement.children = [];
      parser(children, surveyElement.children);
    }

    container.push(surveyElement);
  });
 }

parser(formBuilder.get('fields'), formDefinition);
var json = JSON.stringify(formDefinition)
```

- `item` is the "current" item being provided by the `each` function.
- `index` is the position of that item at its depth within its bounding element

I did not use the `collection` parameter, so I had to investigate. It appears the collection represents all of the elements at the same depth of `item` within a specific bounding element. In other words, if `item` is nested within some other element, then the collection is scoped only to that `parent`.

## Example

- Text Box

  - Checkbox 1
  - Checkbox 2
- Radio Buttons

  - Checkbox 3

Imagine `each` has provided `Text Box`. That will be `item`, with `index` of 0, and `collection` will be an ArrayList with two elements (I'll use javascript syntax for simplicity)  `[{formElement: Text Box},{formElement: Radio Buttons}]`. Next, `each` provides `Checkbox 1`. The `index` will again be 0 since this is the first element at this "depth" and since it is within `Text Box` the `collection` will only contain `Checkbox 1` and `Checkbox 2`. The `each` then provides `Checkbox 2`, `index` is now 1 with `collection` being unchanged.

`each` will continue until it has traversed all of the form elements.